# Is there a notion of a category where morphisms have parity?

Tags: category-theory, terminology, parity

> In category theory, is there a name/notion for categories where the morphisms have a well-defined parity? Formally, this should mean that there is a non-constant functor from the category to the one-object group $B\Bbb Z_2$.
>
> Alternatively, is there a way to reframe such an idea in a sensible way? Perhaps they decompose naturally into some sort of product?

Here are some examples that come to mind:

- The one-object symmetric groups, where parity is the sign of the permutation
- The category of vector spaces (over some field) restricted to invertible maps, where parity is the sign of the determinant.
- My own motivating example came about when thinking about antilinear maps, i.e. additive maps of complex vector space such that $f(\alpha v)=\bar\alpha f(v)$. One approach that I thought of to put these in a framework was to extend the category of complex vector spaces to include as morphisms both linear and antilinear maps. There, parity is of course given by whether the map is linear or antilinear.
- A monoid (as a one-object category) of even and odd functions under multiplication or composition.

Note: I'm realising now that several of these examples have an ambiguity when it comes to the zero-maps: Are they even or odd? I don't think it matters much, but my gut-feeling tells me that we might as well declare such cases as even.

Comment: I suppose you could talk about categories enriched in $\mathsf{B}\Bbb Z/2$

Comment: @FShrike, I don't think that works: the OP's morphism sets are richer than $\Bbb{Z}/2$. I think we need categories that are enriched in the (slice) category of abelian groups over the two-element group: $\mathbf{AbGrp}/(\Bbb{Z}/2)$.

Comment: What's wrong with thinking about categories equipped with a functor to $\mathbf{B} (\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z})$? It captures the idea perfectly.

Comment: @ZhenLin: thank you for saying that: what you say was my immediate reaction, but I got sucked into the details $\ddot{\frown}$. But as a PS, what is this $\mathbf{B}$?

Comment: It's just notation to indicate that we are thinking of a group as a one-object groupoid.

Comment: These are an instance of [locally graded categories](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/graded+set), and may be viewed in terms of enrichment, as well as in terms of functors as proposed by Zhen Lin.

Comment: @varkor Thanks, I guess that pretty much answers the question. However, on wiki I find now that a [graded $\mathcal A$-category](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graded_category) is simply a category with a functor into $\mathcal A$; this was my own idea for a definition. But reading about [locally graded categories](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/locally+graded+category) on nLab, I must say I can't immediately grasp the definition and compare it to graded categories. Does it make more sense to look at the local version for some reason? From what I gather from the "Idea" section, (cont.)

Comment: @varkor (cont.) one difference is that we grade morphism by objects (as opposed to morphisms) in locally graded categories, so I guess the target category must be different than $B\Bbb Z_2$... Which category should we use as target then?

Comment: @Milten: the definition on the nLab is not yet spelled out explicitly, which makes it look more complicated than it is. There's an explicit definition in Paul Levy's [talk slides](https://www.cs.bham.ac.uk/~pbl/papers/locgrade.pdf). The difference between a graded category and a locally graded category is whether you grade the objects, or the morphisms. However, both can be captured by functors. For locally graded categories, you want to map into the delooping of a monoid, which agrees with your original intuition.

Comment: @varkor Thanks for the link, that helped a lot! So to be concrete in my case: The group $\Bbb Z_2$ can be seen as a two-object discrete monoidal category (with the obvious tensor product) - right? So we can say that my "category with parity" is a locally graded category over this monoidal category - right? And then, since the category we grade over is discrete, this should be completely equivalent to a category with a functor into the one-object $B\Bbb Z_2$, i.e. a (non-locally) $B\Bbb Z_2$-graded category - right?

Comment: @Milten: yes, that's right. I've tried to summarise the discussion in an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This answer will essentially be a summary of the comments, although with a few new references to round things off.

A [locally graded category](https://www.cs.bham.ac.uk/%7Epbl/papers/locgrade.pdf) is a notion of category in which the morphisms are graded by the objects of a monoidal category $(\mathcal V, \otimes, I)$, such that the grade of a composite $g \circ f$ is the tensor of the grade of $f$ and the grade of $g$, and identity morphisms have grade $I$. In particular, we can grade by a monoid $V$, viewed as a discrete monoidal category. Taking the monoid $\mathbb Z_2$ gives the notion of category whose morphisms have parity you are describing.

There are various different perspectives on locally graded categories. For instance, we can view a locally $\mathcal V$-graded category as a category [enriched](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/enriched+category) in the presheaf category $[\mathcal V^\circ, \mathbf{Set}]$ whose monoidal structure is given by [Day convolution](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Day+convolution). When $V$ is simply a monoid, we can view a locally $V$-graded category as a category together with a functor to the [delooping](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/delooping) of $V$, i.e. the one-object category whose morphisms are elements of $V$ and whose composition is given by the monoid structure. (This is an example of a "graded category" in the terminology of the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graded_category), but this terminology does not appear to be common, nor does it appear to be the meaning of "graded category" in the paper that the Wikipedia article cites.)

One further perspective on the specific setting you're interested in is given by Shulman's [2-categories with contravariance](https://arxiv.org/abs/1606.05058), where we take the 2-category to be locally discrete (i.e. given by a 2-category with only identity 2-cells).